# How to cache outer scope values to be used inside of Async NodeJS calls?

Tags: node.js, caching, asynchronous, redis

Something like the below code illustrates my intention, if you can imagine how a naive programmer would probably try to write this the first time:

```
function (redisUpdatesHash) {
  var redisKeys = Object.keys(redisUpdatesHash);
  for (var i = 0; i < redisKeys.length; i++) {
    var key = redisKeys[i];
    redisClient.get(key, function (err, value) {
      if (value != redisUpdatesHash[key]) {
        redisClient.set(key, redisUpdatesHash[key]);
        redisClient.publish(key + "/notifications", redisUpdatesHash[key]);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

The problem is, predictably, key is the wrong value in the callback scopes of the asynchronous nature of the node_redis callbacks.  The method of detection is really primitive because of security restrictions out of my control - so the only option for me was to resort to polling the source for it's state.  So the intention above is to store that state in Redis so that I can compare during the next poll to determine if it changed.  If it has, I publish an event and store off the new value to update the comparison value for the next polling cycle.

It appears that there's no good way to do this in NodeJS...  I'm open to any suggestions - whether it's fixing the above code to somehow be able to perform this check, or to suggest a different method of doing this entirely.

Comment: I found a way to do this by using the curry function in HighlandJS. I would prefer to see how this could be done in vanilla node, though. I will post my Highland solution in a moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem through using function currying to cache the outer values in a closure.

In vanilla Javascript/NodeJS

```
asyncCallback = function (newValue, redisKey, redisValue) {
  if (newValue != redisValue) {
    redisClient.set(redisKey, newValue, handleRedisError);
    redisClient.publish(redisKey + '/notifier', newValue, handleRedisError);
  } 
};

curriedAsyncCallback = function (newValue) {
  return function (redisKey) {
    return function (redisValue) {
      asyncCallback(newValue, redisKey, redisValue);
    };
  }; 
};

var newResults = getNewResults(),
    redisKeys = Object.keys(newResults);

for (var i = 0; i < redisKeys.length; i++) {
  redisClient.get(redisKeys[i], curriedAsyncCallback(newResults[redisKeys[i]])(redisKeys[i]));
}
```

However, I ended up using HighlandJS to help with the currying and iteration.

```
var _ = require('highland'),
    //...

asyncCallback = function (newValue, redisKey, redisValue) {
  if (newValue != redisValue) {
    redisClient.set(redisKey, newValue, handleRedisError);
    redisClient.publish(redisKey + '/notifier', newValue, handleRedisError);
  } 
};

var newResults = getNewResults(),
    redisKeys = Object.keys(newResults),
    curriedAsyncCallback = _.curry(asyncCallback),
    redisGet = _(redisClient.get.bind(redisClient));

redisKeys.each(function (key) {
  redisGet(key).each(curriedAsyncCallback(newResults[key], key));
});
```